# Equivalence relation on a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, equivalence-relations

I have the following question:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. We define a relation $\sim$ on $G
>  \backslash \left\{e\right\} = \left\{ g \in G : g \neq e \right\}$ by
>   $g \sim h$ if and only if there exists $k$ such that $g = h^k$
>
> 1) Show that $\sim$ is reflexive and transitive
>
> 2) Show that $\sim$ is symmetric if and only if the order of $g$ is
>   prime for every $g \neq e$.

**1)** Clearly $\sim$ is reflexive as for $k=1$ we have $g = g^1$ so $g \sim g$.

To show it is transitive, suppose $g \sim h$, so there exists a $k_1$ such that $g = h^{k_1}$, further suppose $h \sim l$ so there exists a $k_2$ such that $ h = l^{k_2}$ so we need to show that there exists a $k_3$ such that $g = l^{k_3}$ which implies $g \sim l$

I get a bit stuck at this point, because I'm unsure whether all $g \in G$ have finite orders or not. I know $G$ is a finite group, does this imply that all $g \in G$ are of finite order?

The working I've done so far, which assumes that all $g$ are of finite order, goes like this:

As $h$ is of finite order, let $o(h) = \lambda$

Since $g = h^{k_1}$ this implies that $g = h^{n\lambda + k_1}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

As $l$ is of finite order, let $o(l) = \mu$

Likewise we get that $h = l^{m\mu + k_2}$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

So $h^{\lambda+1-k_1} g = h = l^{k_2}$

$g = h^{k_1 -1} l^{k_2}$

It's at this point I don't really know how to go forward (which is making me think I've tackled the problem incorrectly, but I don't see another way)

Thanks, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part (2), you can use the formula that says that if $\lvert x \rvert$ is the (finite) order of the element $x$ of the group $G$, then
$$
\lvert x^k \rvert = \frac{\lvert x \rvert}{\gcd(k, \lvert x \rvert)}.\tag{ordpow}
$$
So if the order of $x$ is not a prime, write $\lvert x \rvert = m n$, with $m, n > 1$. Then $1 \ne y = x^ m$ has order $n < m n$, and there's no way to write $x$ as a power of $y$.

On the other hand, if $x$ has prime order $p$, and $1 \ne x^k = y$, then $p$ does not divide $k$, so $\gcd(p,k) = 1$. [Find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem) $u,v$ such that $p u + k v = 1$, and then
$$
x = x^1 = x^{p u + k v} = (x^k)^v = y^v. 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, is this pretty much the only 'non-long winded' way to solve part (2) - I only ask because Lagrange's Theorem isn't actually covered until the next chapter, so I think the question is wanting me to answer it without using it.

Comment: @Noble. you're welcome. There are surely other ways of looking at it, but this sounds to me as direct as it could be.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try solving it without using it, and as a last resort I'll provide a solution using Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: @Noble. wait a minute, I'm not using Lagrange, only the formula (ordpow), which is elementary, and does not require Lagrange.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, this isn't Lagrange's theorem. I saw that the ordpow equation you stated was in the next chapter in my notes and assumed (stupidly) it was Lagrange's theorem. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Noble. alright!

Comment: @Andreas Caranti Can you please elaborate? I was able to do the other side but I can't figure why symmetry implies that the order must be prime?